# How can I map my custom ADFS attribute to a AWS Cognito user pool attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0, adfs

I have an AWS Cognito user pool, and the ability to be federated into that user pool with ADFS. On the ADFS server are a number of groups that define users permissions. I am trying to translate the group membership over from ADFS to AWS so that the same permissions can be enforced with Cognito.

The way I have tried to do this is a custom claim rule that returns 'true' if the user is part of a certain group:

```
    c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid", 
    Value == "The-Group-SID", 
    Issuer =~ "^AD AUTHORITY$"]
    => issue(Type = "Dev", Value = "true");
```

This works and when a member of the Group specified signs in, the SAML response carries an attribute with the name "Dev" and the value of "true"

Saml Response

```
    <Attribute Name="Dev">
        <AttributeValue>True</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
```

Next I go into the AWS Console and attempt to map this attribute to a cognito attribute:

Saml Provider: ADFS

Capture: Checked; Saml Attribute: Dev; User Pool Attribute: custom:isin-ADFS-Dev;

However this ADFS attribute is not mapped to my custom Cognito attribute, as in it doesn't show up in Cognito User Pool as an attribute of the user. Does anyone know why I am failing to correctly map the attributes? Thanks!

Comment: Your pictures did not post. Please copy the text into your question and not use pictures.

Comment: @JohnHanley Clicking on the photos still takes you to the photo hosted on Imgur, but I will post the text as well. One moment

Comment: In Chrome on my system (Windows 10), your pictures do not show up - just a placeholder where an image should be.

Comment: Yes it is the same for me (very annoying), but if you click the placeholder it takes you to the Imgur page hosting it.

Comment: Clicking the placeholder does nothing on my system. However, ignore this, just put the text in your question instead of pictures / picture links as required by StackOverflow.

Comment: @JohnHanley Edited. Thanks for letting me know the images weren't rendering

Comment: Can you try mapping "Dev" to a not custom user pool attribute for testing purposes?

Comment: This command will show you the attribute mapping that you have setup: `aws cognito-idp describe-identity-provider --user-pool-id USER_POOL_ID --provider-name PROVIDER_NAME`

Comment: Hey @JohnHanley sorry for the late reply. I mapped the Cognito custom attribute to a non custom SAML attribute and it was mapped correctly. This implies that I am grabbing the attribute wrong in the SAML, but I am not sure exactly why, I will follow this rabbit hole.

Comment: @bflynnigan I have the exact same problem and symptoms. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @Magnuss No sorry man. For our use case we ended up using ADFS purely for authentication. And then a collection of custom roles in our webservice for Authorization. Sorry couldn't be much more help

Comment: FWIW the problem I had, was that the custom attributes weren't enabled in App Client settings under "Set attribute read and write permissions".